# How to join arrays using Lo-Dash

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lodash

Since I’m trying out Lo-Dash, I’m wondering how to join and sort two arrays?

`A1: [ 3, 1 ]`

`A2: [ { 1: ‘val 1’ }, { 2: ‘val 2’ }, { 3: ‘val 3’ }, { 4: ‘val 4’ }, … ]`

`A1 join A2 orderBy Vals: [ { 1: ‘val 1’ }, { 3: ‘val 3’ }]`

Sorting seems straightforward using `_.sortBy`.  But how can a join be performed?

Comment: That's not valid JavaScript you got there. Do you mean `[ { 1: 'val 1' }, { 2: 'val 2' },...]` It would still be a strange structure but it would be valid at least.

Comment: as of lodash 4.x _join is a supported method for arrays, ref: https://lodash.com/docs#join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to have to make a few assumptions to answer your question. Firstly, like Louis [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22263307/how-to-join-arrays-using-lo-dash#comment33817925_22263307) in the comments, `A2` isn't valid Javascript. So let's go with what Louis suggests and instead use the format `[{ 1: 'val 1' }, ...]`. Secondly, are the objects in `A2` guaranteed to have only one key, or do we need to search through those? For simplicity I'll assume the former.

Given these assumptions, the following would work:

```js
_.filter(A2, function(d) {
  return _.contains(A1, _.parseInt(_.keys(d)[0]));
});
```

Unlike most of Lo-dash's functions, the ones used here don't perform too much abstraction from plain ol' Javascript. Given a browser that supports ECMAScript 5, you can replace the Lodash wrappers with the following to get the same functionality:

```js
A2.filter(function(d) {
  return A1.indexOf(parseInt(Object.keys(d)[0])) !== -1;
});
```

Comment: Yes indeed A2's keys are unique.  Thanks for the solution.  I've no guarantee that ECMA5-supporting browsers will be used.  Does the Lo-dash solution work also for non-ECMA5 browsers?

Comment: Yes. Lo-dash has a fallback implementation in case Object.keys isn't available.